# Как в kohana присвоить стиль через строку?

Tags: kohana, view

Объясните, пожалуйста, как в kohana через такую строку `$this->template->styles = '';` можно присвоить стиль? Не понимаю, как оно работает изнутри. Материал взял http://kohanaframework.su/starting/base_controller

Или еще пример: `$this->template->title = 'О сайте';`, а потом это как-то выводят с помощью одной переменной `$title`.

Comment: @sew810i9_I9, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите реализацию `Kohana_Controller_Template`.
В `Kohana_Controller_Template::before()` создается отображение (`View`), в `Kohana_Controller_Template::after()` - рендерится.

Как выводится одной переменной: смотрите `Kohana_View`.
Начините с `Kohana_View::render()`, оттуда дойдете до `Kohana_View::capture()`, где и происходит магия [extract()](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php)

Comment: я извлек через extract переменную title, из массива array('title' => $title); - это в самом контроллере вида сделано, в нем же пишу echo $title, выводится значение. Но в самом файле вида почему-то не выводится, если написать echo $title. 
http://ideone.com/joj8qZ

Comment: потому что вы удалили кусок кода из ``capture()``?